# Icon Image appears Incredibly small on Jbutton | Java

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

For a small project, I'm trying to make a TicTacToe Game using JFrame and JButtons. The game is going to consist of 9 Buttons that when clicked will changed to either an X or O. I havent gotten too far into the project but The problem I'm running into is when I display an image as an Icon on the Jbutton, Its incredibly small and Ive tried to resize it with no avail. Any feedback is appreciated.

This is what the button looks like when i put the icon on it:
[Image of small button when Icon on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9t8Kk.png)

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TicTacToe
{
  public static void main ( String[] args )
   {
ButtonFrame frm = new ButtonFrame("TicTactToe");

frm.setSize(300, 450);     
frm.setVisible( true );

  }
}


class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
JButton bChange; 


ButtonFrame(String title) 
{
    super( title );

    ImageIcon XIcon = new ImageIcon("X.png");
    Icon OIcon = new ImageIcon("O.png");


    setLayout( new FlowLayout() );      // set the layout manager

    //top row
    bChange = new JButton(XIcon);  
    add( bChange );
    setSize(400, 400);                      


    bChange = new JButton("Button2");  
    add( bChange );                      


    bChange = new JButton("Button3");  
    add( bChange );                      


    //middle row
    bChange = new JButton("Button4");  
    add( bChange );                      


    bChange = new JButton("Button5");  
    add( bChange );                      


    bChange = new JButton("Button6");  
    add( bChange );                      


    //bottom row
    bChange = new JButton("Button7");  
    add( bChange );                      


    bChange = new JButton("Button8");  
    add( bChange );                      


    bChange = new JButton("Button9");  
    add( bChange );                      

    setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the `JFrame` gets it you want to `setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );`

Comment: You may prefer using a `GridLayout(3,3)`, for the panel holding the buttons.

Comment: Buttons have default margins. When you create one with only an image you should set the margin to a small number. `JButton.setInsets(1, 1 ,1, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems to be the image you are using. when I copied your code and used my own image the program worked properly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/io2yV.png

Comment: I changed the images like you said and it still is super tiny despite the image being 1000x1000 pixels. Could it just be because of the compiler I'm using or the JFrame?

Comment: have you made sure that there is no typo is the name of your file? is the picture stored in the correct location? when I add an image that does not exist my result is very similar to yours.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The computers Im normally coding on use user profiles and program couldn't seem to pull the images if they where in the same place file so I put them onto the C: drive of the computer and used the file destination and It worked fine.